# One tablet app, one flow with two users (specialist and customer) - how to differentiate?

Tags: gui-design, interface, workflow, tablet, flow

I am working on a project that involves creating User Interface of a tablet app. The app will be used in the following way:

1. a customer is coming to the shop
2. a specialist is starting the app and initiates the flow
3. a specialist gives the tablet to the customer and the customer is
   continuing the same flow
4. after a customer is done with his part of the flow the tablet is
   given back to the specialist who continues the flow

The question is:
do you have any suggestions how should the UI be differentiated so that it is clear which part of the flow is dedicated for the specialist and which is deicated for the customer?
Do you have any good examples of similar flows?

Comment: I don't have a good answer to your question, but it made me think about this article: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2016/09/how-great-onboarding-leads-to-great-ux/

On-board your specialist and customer. Are specialist and customer always interacting at certain 'fixed' point in the flow, or can this differ?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise looking at existing applications that have both client-facing and employee-facing flows for inspiration. One big category of examples is the modern tablet/smartphone-based point-of-sale systems, where the employee hands the device to the customer to input a tip, sign the credit slip, and choose a receipt option.

The keys to making this work well are:

1. **Clear instructions for both the employee and customer.** The interface should prompt the employee to hand the device to the customer and vice-versa.
2. **A concise customer-facing flow that guides the user to completion.** Limiting the number of choices and the amount of time that customer has to use the device unassisted by an employee is key to success.

By way of example, the customer-facing screens in the Square iPad app are single-minded, going so far as to hide the device status bar (time/battery/etc.) and simply focusing on the path to completion.

**Employee-facing interface:**

[image]

**Customer-facing interface:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A stacked progress bar might be a good visual indicator to start -- the scenario I'm imagining is a car dealer two individuals filling out a multi-step form together. If the indicator was "0" customer steps "X" specialist steps "0000XXXX0000XXXX" - as the users progress through "**0000**XXXX0000XXXX" an additional labeled call out along with the visual indicator would good "these steps are for **customer**" the pattern should be recognized quickly